# How to detect curves and straight paths using GPS coordinates?

Tags: python, gps, interpolation

I'm working on a project involving railway tracks and I'm trying to find an algorithm that could detect curves(left/right) or straight lines based on time-series GPS coordinates.

The data contains latitude, longitude, and altitude values along with many different sensor readings of a vehicle in a specific range of time.

Example dataframe of a curve looks as follows:

```
   latitude longitude altitude
1  43.46724 -5.823470    145.0
2  43.46726 -5.823653    145.2
3  43.46728 -5.823837    145.4
4  43.46730 -5.824022    145.6
5  43.46730 -5.824022    145.6
6  43.46734 -5.824394    146.0
7  43.46738 -5.824768    146.3
8  43.46738 -5.824768    146.3
9  43.46742 -5.825146    146.7
10 43.46742 -5.825146    146.7
11 43.46746 -5.825527    147.1
12 43.46746 -5.825527    147.1
13 43.46750 -5.825910    147.3
14 43.46751 -5.826103    147.4
15 43.46753 -5.826295    147.6
16 43.46753 -5.826489    147.8
17 43.46753 -5.826685    148.1
18 43.46753 -5.826878    148.2
19 43.46752 -5.827073    148.4
20 43.46750 -5.827266    148.6
21 43.46748 -5.827458    148.9
22 43.46744 -5.827650    149.2
23 43.46741 -5.827839    149.5
24 43.46736 -5.828029    149.7
25 43.46731 -5.828212    150.1
26 43.46726 -5.828393    150.4
27 43.46720 -5.828572    150.5
28 43.46713 -5.828746    150.8
29 43.46706 -5.828914    151.0
30 43.46698 -5.829078    151.2
31 43.46690 -5.829237    151.4
32 43.46681 -5.829392    151.6
33 43.46671 -5.829540    151.8
34 43.46661 -5.829680    152.0
35 43.46650 -5.829816    152.2
36 43.46639 -5.829945    152.4
37 43.46628 -5.830066    152.4
38 43.46616 -5.830180    152.4
39 43.46604 -5.830287    152.5
40 43.46591 -5.830384    152.6
41 43.46579 -5.830472    152.8
42 43.46566 -5.830552    152.9
43 43.46552 -5.830623    153.2
44 43.46539 -5.830687    153.4
45 43.46526 -5.830745    153.6
46 43.46512 -5.830795    153.8
47 43.46499 -5.830838    153.9
48 43.46485 -5.830871    153.9
49 43.46471 -5.830895    154.0
50 43.46458 -5.830911    154.2
51 43.46445 -5.830919    154.3
52 43.46432 -5.830914    154.7
53 43.46418 -5.830896    155.1
54 43.46406 -5.830874    155.6
55 43.46393 -5.830842    155.9
56 43.46381 -5.830803    156.0
57 43.46368 -5.830755    155.5
58 43.46356 -5.830700    155.3
59 43.46332 -5.830575    155.1
```

I've found out about spline interpolation on this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737294/how-to-detect-curves-on-gps-tracks) in *Stackoverflow* asking the same question and decided to apply it in my problem:

```
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

## read csv file with pandas
df = pd.read_csv("Curvas/Curva_2.csv")
   
# take latitude and longitude columns
df['latitude'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
df['longitude'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)

# plot the data
# df.plot(x='longitude', y='latitude', style='o')
# plt.show()

# using longitude and latitude data, use spline interpolation to create a new curve
x = df['longitude']
y = df['latitude']
xnew = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), x.shape[0])

ynew = make_interp_spline(xnew, y)(x)
plt.plot(xnew, ynew, zorder=2)
plt.show()

## Error results using different coordinates/routes
## Curve_1 → Left (e = 0.04818886515888465)
## Curve_2 → Left (e = 0.019459215874292113)    
## Straight_1 → Straight (e = 0.03839597167971931)
```

I've calculated the error between the interpolated points and the real ones but I'm not quite sure how to proceed next or what threshold to use to figure out the direction.

[image: Curve Example 2]